# Pass a 2D pointer array to function

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, malloc

I'm new to C programming and have to write a small program where I should do stuff with a matrix (Input and solve a list of equations stored in a 2D Matrix). Individually the different functions of the program (input the matrix, calculate the solution, output the matrix) are no problem. In this (shortened) version of the code, the `void* getMatrix` creates a matrix and assigns some values to each position in the matrix. I can access these in the main function with no problem.

But how can I pass this matrix (or better: a pointer to the matrix) to another function and access and edit it there?

I am not allowed to pass the values of the matrix, but instead have to use a pointer to the storage location of it.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* getMatrix(int *nPoint);
void doStuffWithMatrix(/*Pass matrix*/);

int main() {
    int n = 8; 
    int *nPoint = &n;

    float (*matrix)[*nPoint] = getPointer(nPoint);

    //Print out the matrix
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < *nPoint; i++) {
        printf("| ");
        for (int j = 0; j < *nPoint+1; j++) {
            printf("%-5g | ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    doStuffWithMatrix(matrix);

    free(*matrix);
}

void* getMatrix(int *nPoint) {
    //Create 2D Matrix
    float (*matrix)[*nPoint] = malloc(sizeof(float[*nPoint][*nPoint + 1]));

    //Temporary value assign
    for (int i = 0; i < *nPoint; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *nPoint+1; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = 10 * (i + 1) + (j + 1);
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

void printMatrix(/*Pass matrix*/) {
    //Do Stuff
}
```

The function `doStuffWithMatrix` is just a placeholder and obviously doesn't work.

Note: I coded in Java before and thats why I put the `{` in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Return the address of first element of matrix in `int* getMatrix` and same can be passed into function by using `Yourfunction(getMatrix(nPoint));`